# Server Error in '/' Application. Unspecified error [ 5,sqlcese40.dll ]

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

Can somebody please help me?

After receiving an email from Google yesterday that advised a couple of links in my site (www.bigint.biz) were broken, I repaired them.  Then I made a change to the sitemap.

Afterwards, when accessing the site I received the message:  Server Error in '/' Application, Runtime Error, This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

So, I put the site exactly back how it was before the changes to the sitemap; but, I received 
an internal server error 500 error message.

Then, I removed the whole site from the host provider and uploaded it again with the original version that worked fine with no joy.

Since, I have set the customErrors tag "mode" attribute to "Off" to get a more detailed error message - below:

---

Server Error in '/' Application. 
Unspecified error [ 5,sqlcese40.dll ]

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: Unspecified error [ 5,sqlcese40.dll ]

Source Error:     Line 2:  @{     Line 3:         Line 4:       WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("PhotoGallery", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", true);

Source File:   \web-123win\winpackage22\XXX.COM\web\content_AppStart.cshtml    Line:  4

```
Stack Trace: 

[SqlCeException (0x80004005): Unspecified error [ 5,sqlcese40.dll ]]
   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open(Boolean silent) +2182
   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open() +47
   WebMatrix.Data.Database.EnsureConnectionOpen() +44
   WebMatrix.Data.<QueryInternal>d__0.MoveNext() +66
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +164
   WebMatrix.Data.Database.QuerySingle(String commandText, Object[] args) +103
   WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseWrapper.QuerySingle(String commandText, Object[] parameters) +14
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CheckTableExists(IDatabase db, String tableName) +57
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateTablesIfNeeded() +49
   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeMembershipProvider(SimpleMembershipProvider simpleMembership, DatabaseConnectionInfo connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean createTables) +73
   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeProviders(DatabaseConnectionInfo connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables) +51
   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(String connectionStringName, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables) +51
   ASP._Page__appstart_cshtml.Execute() in \\web-123win\winpackage22\bigint.biz\www.bigint.biz\web\content\_AppStart.cshtml:4
   System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.<ExecuteInternal>b__0() +65
   System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.<GetSafeExecuteStartPageThunk>b__3(Action action) +7
   System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.ExecuteInternal() +78
   System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.ExecuteStartPageInternal(HttpApplication application, Action`1 monitorFile, IVirtualPathFactory virtualPathFactory, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions) +184
   System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.ExecuteStartPage(HttpApplication application, Action`1 monitorFile, IVirtualPathFactory virtualPathFactory, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions) +30

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown.]
   System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.ExecuteStartPage(HttpApplication application, Action`1 monitorFile, IVirtualPathFactory virtualPathFactory, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions) +96
   System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationStartPage.ExecuteStartPage(HttpApplication application) +170
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.StartApplication(HttpApplication application, Action`1 executeStartPage, EventHandler applicationStart) +126
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.StartApplication(HttpApplication application) +71
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication application) +127
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +418
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9874568
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

---

I noticed that when I was uploading the site again  using FileZilla Client that 4 files failed to copy to the host; however, the same files are in the host bin directory as they did not originally delete for some reason - access rights I think.  The files are:

web/content/bin/X86/sqlceer40ENN.dll

web/content/bin/X86/sqlceqp40.dll

web/content/bin/X86/sqlcese40.dll

web/content/bin/X86/sqlceme40.dll

---

Is this just coincidence, as the error message references one of these files?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT - I have found a little more info here but I am struggling to understand how it can help me: http://www.blakepell.com/Blog/?p=227

I have got the site back up and running for the minute by removing: WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("PhotoGallery", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", true);

But the issue still exists

Comment: i think the issue is with Connection string

Comment: Thanks Saghir. Could you be more specific please?

Comment: Agree with @Saghir, but this could be a dll issue since it worked before but not since failed upload of dll files. If everything you need is in you solution output then always do a clean upload, i.e. delete existing files on target so only file adds, no updates.

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason when I delete all the files from the web hosts the bin folder contents with the dll's remains?.  I will try and get the web content folder (root) re-set and try again if no other solution is proposed.

Comment: sounds more and more like dll file issue, like it can't even execute on it, rip those puppies out!

Answer (score 0):

I picked this problem up again today all this time later and found the solution with research.  This is how I got there.

Replacing the dll files as recommended above didn't work before.

So, I started again by switching off my custom errors page which enabled me to get to get to the error code again.

I Googled the error and research pointed to a connection string issue or a folder permissions issue.

It's a good job I checked the permissions again because I previously set the folder permissions in the App_Data folder where the .sdf database was to enable read and write access using FileZilla but nothing actually changed.  It seemed to work because changes appeared to cascade down through all the sub directories, but it didn't work.

The permissions were not actually changed using the FTP method although it looked like it had happened.  I only found out because another post that I saw today suggested changing permissions through the control panel so I went back there to check them only to see a padlock by the folders.

So, I unlocked the folder permissions on App_Data correctly this time in the control panel file manager.  I then un-commented the web security code below in the _AppStart page again and tried the site online and it worked.

Finally, I set custom errors back to on.

The moral is use the control panel and not FTP client to change folder permissions on hosted folders.  I hope this helps someone else.